# easymock method matcher for class argument

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have a method with signature as follows:

```
    public <T extends S> T foo(final Class<T> clazz){
       .....
       .....
    }
```

How do I mock this method in easymock?

I tried following two lines in my test class but still the expected object is not returned, so I get NullPointerException.

```
    Capture<Class<MyClass>> classCapture = new Capture<Class<MyClass>>();
            expect(someObject.foo(EasyMock.capture(classCapture))).andReturn(testObject);
```

And testObject is initialized in the test class, which I want to get returned when

```
    foo()
```

is called. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you *have* to mock that method?  It only accepts a `Class`, and that's really easy to put into the method.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just match for `anyObject(Class.class)`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to capture the variable in this instance, but your problem is the way you typed your command means you are looking for a method `foo()` without any arguments.

You need to you need to use `and()` to chain the capture and the argument matcher requirements for the method call:

```
expect(someObject.foo(EasyMock.and(
                            EasyMock.capture(classCapture),
                            anyObject()))
                      )
            .andReturn(testObject);
```

Then after you call your mock in replay mode you can get the captured argument back with `capture.getValue()`

```
    replay(someObject);

    assertSame(testObject, someObject.foo(MyClass.class));

    assertEquals(MyClass.class, classCapture.getValue());
```